# How to add extra fields by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I Have 2 radio button where I can choose what kind of inputs I like to use `text field, text-area, etc.` now I want to add `Add` & `Remove` buttons in order to add extra fields or remove them.

### Here are my codes

`HTML`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div id="moreless"></div> //show buttons
  <div class="fields" id="fields"></div> //show fields
</div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {

    $(".fieldtype").on('change', function() {
      var date_al = $(".fieldtype:checked").val();
      if(date_al == 'textfield') {
        $('#fields').empty();
        $('#moreless').empty();
        $('#fields').append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="">');
        $('#moreless').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button>');
      }else{
        $('#fields').empty();
        $('#moreless').empty();
        $('#fields').append('<textarea class="form-control" name="" id="" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>');
        $('#moreless').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button>');
      }
  });
</script>
```

`Screenshot`

[image: one]
[image: two]

### Question

What should I do to get my `Add` & `Remove` buttons to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript should look something like the following:

```
var textFieldsCount = 0;

function addTextField(){
textFieldsCount++;
$('#fields').append('<div id="textField-' + textFieldsCount + '"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="'+ textFieldsCount.toString() +'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="removeTextField(\'textField-' + textFieldsCount.toString() + '\')">Remove</button></div></div>');
}

function removeTextField(elementId){
    var selector = "#" + elementId;
    console.log(selector);
    $(selector).remove();
    textFieldsCount--;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fieldtype").on('change', function() {
    var date_al = $(".fieldtype:checked").val();
    if (date_al == 'textfield') {
      textFieldsCount++;
      $('#fields').empty();
      $('#moreless').empty();
      $('#fields').append('<div id="textField-' + textFieldsCount + '"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="" id="'+ textFieldsCount.toString() +'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="removeTextField(\'textField-' + textFieldsCount.toString() + '\')">Remove</button></div></div>');
      $('#moreless').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="addTextField();">Add</button>');
    } else {
      $('#fields').empty();
      $('#moreless').empty();
      $('#fields').append('<textarea class="form-control" name="" id="" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>');
      $('#moreless').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button>');
    }
  });
});
```

Also, I suggest that you have a remove button in front of each text box instead of one remove button.

Similar logic can be used for textareas.

Comment: This is not working, now when i click on radio buttons nothing shows

Comment: sorry it was extra `});` in my code, but there is small issue, when i click on remove button it removes all of them except removing fields one by one from last one to first one.

Comment: My pleasure buddy

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use Document.createElement function of JS.

It is a better and a faster approach to use JavaScript's API to create and add element. [This link](https://howchoo.com/g/mmu0nguznjg/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom) provides a good explanation (with metrics) on why it is better to use Document.createElement to create elements.

You can get more reference here on how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

This is how you can add new fields when clicked on add button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-btn', function() {
  var date_al = $(".fieldtype:checked").val();
  var element;
  if(date_al === 'textfield') {
      element = document.createElement("input");
      element.type = "text";
      element.className = "form-control";
  }else{
      element = document.createElement("textarea");
      element.className = "form-control";
  }

  if(element) {
      var fieldsContainer = document.getElementById('fields');
      fieldsContainer.appendChild(element);
  }

});
```

Comment: Hi, This is to show text when page loads, i need to make it happen **by clicking** on buttons `add` & `remove`

Comment: @mafortis, updated the answer with an example and an explanation of a better way to handle your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
  //show buttons
    <div class="fields" id="fields">
      <lable for='text'>text</lable>
      <input type='radio' id='text' name='element' checked>
      <lable for='textarea'>textarea</lable>
      <input type='radio' id='textarea' name='element'>
    </div> //show fields
    <div id="moreless">
      <button onclick="change('input')">
    add
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
```